# Function keeps on removing documents from repeat control

Tags: java, xpages

I have a xp:repeat control with a list of entries. For each entry I have defined a button to remove the back-end document from the database:

```
<xp:button value="Delete" id="button2">
    <i class="fa fa-trash">&#160;</i>
    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="complete">
        <xp:this.action>
            <![CDATA[#{javascript:employeeBean.remove(obj.unid)}]]>
        </xp:this.action>
    </xp:eventHandler>
</xp:button>
```

This works fine although I notice an odd behavior: when I refresh the page (F5 in browser) I get a message: Confirm Form Resubmission. In case I select Confirm another entry is removed from the list.

This process continues as long as I press F5 and refresh the page. How can I stop this?

The remove method is not rocket-science:

```
public void remove(String id) {
    try {
        Document doc;
        openDatabaseAndView();
        if (id != null) {
            doc = view.getDocumentByKey(id, true);
        } else {
            doc = null;
        }
        if (doc != null) {
            doc.remove(true);
        } else {
              //message to user
        }
        closeDatabaseAndView();
    } catch (NotesException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I placed the repeat control within a panel and set a partial refresh on this panel from the Delete button...

Answer (score 0):

F5 with form resubmition in fact repeats last request (delete) that executes button click again, and again...

Take a look at "POST/GET" pattern: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18821569/206265